# Should i remove wainscoting to allow flooded walls to dry out?

Tags: flooding, weep-hole

We have a bay window with a French Drain just outside. We used to have gutters and a large downspout that drained into the French Drain, but during roof replace in 2002 the workers damaged the gutters when they removed them to replace the decking. We have not yet had the money to replace them.

As an intermediate step, we dug out the area to allow the water to drain directly into the drain and we keep that area clear. We removed any wood that may have been placed as decorative to allow any water to drain away.

We live on a hill and have not gotten water in before this storm. The house has never had a flood claim since being built in 1979.

We have a slab foundation and vinyl plank flooring adhered to the slab.

Harvey dumped almost 52" of rain at our home, almost half that in a few hours one night. Which is when we noticed water seeping in under the baseboards at the bay window.

We dammed the area with every towel we own and I spent a sleepless night mopping up all the water, filling my 2.5 gallon bucket twice, and sopping up any water that seeped out of that area with the towels.

The following night we had just a tiny bit of water get in.

My suspicion is that the water came in through the weep holes because the French Drain wasn't large enough to handle the amount of water that it needed to handle. Our neighbor's French Drain attaches to ours outside the fence line. Theirs backed up. Ours may have as well, although we had scoped out any dirt that may have managed to get into the main drain and our shunt before the storm hit in preparation.

My question is two-fold.

1) There is wainscoting paneling and a baseboard on the interior wall of the bay window. Should I pull that to dry things out? And how?

2) What else should I be looking for?!

[Area of Damage] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JudZT.jpg)

In the photo there is some discoloration near the floor. There is also a "ripple" in the panel. Those were there before the storm. I think they showed up after we had galvanized pipe burst in the house in 2012.

Comment: Can you add photos? On the plus side, the kind of rain you have seen is not common. Can you confirm the drain is functioning again? From what you have said thus far, it does sound like the water came in because it had nowhere else to go (easily).  Its not a bad idea to get the baseboard off and a fan on the area to dry it out. If you dont own an assortment of prybars and small screwdrivers (Home Depot has them, like screw drivers that have a "scraper" on the end). Start at a outside corner, work your way in, gently, little at a time. This only works if it is nailed on.

Comment: Which part would you like photos of? I will certainly attempt to attach them.

Comment: Mainly the drain in reference to the window area. A picture of the inner wall that the water was coming in from would help if you want further guidance on how (and if) you should remove anything. BTW, Ultimately I think you can leave the paneling, but getting the molding off will tell us.

Comment: Photo isnt clickable, if you use tinypic/imgur/photobucket it could be. If the wall was already damaged, are you looking to do a repair? Get a fan in the area either way, to help it dry. I would remove the baseboard on the outer edged, then the inner piece, to help it dry even better. You will also see the status under it, but it would allow more air inside. (assuming it is nailed)

Comment: We aren't too concerned with repairing previous damage yet. It may be folded into the cost of repairing the storm damage, but we aren't clear yet. No one has made it out because much of the area is still under water. I will go to Home Depot tomorrow and get the tools and pull the baseboards, though. I don't want mold.

Comment: Get a fan on it if you haven't already. Since the water came in from the bottom up, its likely the water left as easily as it got in (for the most part). So its really just a matter of getting it dry. Whatever damage the water did is there already it sounds like (from even a previous issue) and while it probably "made it worse" getting it dry is probably the easiest and least expensive thing you can do at this point.

Comment: You're a life saver! I will update as soon as I get into it. I'll pick up more mold retardant like the one we used before we replaced the damaged sheetrock from the pipes bursting.

Comment: In addition to the fan, your air conditioner can help pull moisture out of the air and allow it to dry out. Also, if you have a de-humidifier available you could park that right there in the area for a week or two.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I finally got the tool to remove the baseboards and apparently these were replaced when we had to re-pipe the house in 2012. The new baseboards were then glued on. The additional quarter round the added at the bottom of the baseboards after installing the vinyl plank flooring  was also glued on. So how do I remove that without damaging it? We run the A/C set to 69 degrees (because I had a heat stroke and cannot handle temperatures above a certain level) all the time. Haven't noticed any discoloration or odor. I'll be getting a mold test kit to monitor conditions. Ideas?

Comment: I'll be honest, I was hoping it was not glued on. Getting air moving over it and as @ArchonOSX has added, AC/Dehumidifier to help dry the air is going to help. From what you have described, it sounds like the paneling and the baseboard already has water damage. You implied you have intentions of doing work in that area. It's going to have to be a judgement call on your part if you want to open it up to get it dry faster & see what it looks like, or if you'd prefer not to damage it further and just work on "drying it out".  You can try a hacksaw blade+patience but its going to ding it up

Comment: The paneling is getting a cracked appearance, so it'll be sooner rather than later. I'll probably drill a couple of holes to add some ventilation. Then start looking for a price of paneling that looks similar to replace it.

Comment: I finally located my pry tools and my moisture meter. So the baseboards are off, not just having fans blow on them. Good thing because the meter pinged red and beeped just about everywhere below knee level in the bay window. I am trying to rope in some young backs who can help pull the paneling and tank the insulation. Then I treat it with a vengeance. Musty and muddy  doesn't begin to describe to odor. Even the baseboards were easy to remove with it being so moist. Now we start repairing. yeah. I'll be back with more questions.

Comment: I will start a new thread for the tear-out and repair. The quarter-round and baseboards are off with fans blowing on it.